# Form validation on submit don't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Hi so i was reading how to validate html forms, all my validators client side are working woth patterns and type. The problem is when i press submit the javascript validation dont run. There is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">

function validateForm()
{
    var xa = document.forms["regform"]["password"].value;
    var xb = document.forms["regform"]["password2"].value;
    var xc = document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
    var xd = document.forms["regform"]["email2"].value;
    if (xa == xb && xc == xd){
        return true; }
    else{ return false; alert("Please enter a valid captcha code");}
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    try {
    $("body select").msDropDown();
    } catch(e) {
    alert(e.message);
    }
    });

</script>
```

Them the form:

```
<form name="regform" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="actions/register_acc.php" method="post">

<input type="password" name="password" class="input-style" required="required">
<input type="password2" name="password" class="input-style" required="required">

<input name="email" class="input-style" placeholder="your@email.com" required="required" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
<input name="email2" class="input-style" placeholder="your@email.com" required="required" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">

<input type="submit" value="ok">

</form>
```

Inside the form i also have these:

```
<select name="selectname" id="webmenu">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

And in the head these:

```
<script src="js/msdropdown/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked developers console? What do you mean - not work? You don't see an alert - so you won't as `return false` stops any other function execution.

Comment: It returns always true

Comment: `password2` isn't a valid `input` type.

Comment: already fixed that, i just mess up when i copy on stackoverflow. Its not that.

Comment: I'd try removing the `return` and just providing the function

Comment: What library are you using to get `msDropDown`?

Comment: If i remove `return` happens the same.

Comment: What is `body select`?

Comment: I got one Jquery `<select>`.

Comment: Also, can you answer my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528802/form-validation-on-submit-dont-work#comment58747200_35528802)? Thanks :).

Comment: I just updated the post with all the content of the msDropDown.

Comment: I am testing on a fiddle, do you know of any CDN sites that I can use?

Comment: I dont know what CDN sites are, sorry. newbie programmer here.

Comment: Okay, that's okay :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `validateForm` method itself, specifically in the `else` block. You're returning `false` before the `alert` call. Swap the two calls around and you should see the `alert` message appear.

For clarity's sake, I would change the message in the alert box as it isn't directly relevant to the fields you're validating.

```
function validateForm()
{
  var xa = document.forms["regform"]["password"].value;
  var xb = document.forms["regform"]["password2"].value;
  var xc = document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
  var xd = document.forms["regform"]["email2"].value;
  if (xa == xb && xc == xd){
    return true; 
  }
  else { 
    alert("Please enter a valid captcha code");
    return false;
  }
}
```

See this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gz8o1zk/)**